# Data Processing connectivity in Neptune ML

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-neptune, data-processing

I am having issues requesting a processing job via Neptune ML. In particular, I am sending this request on my SageMaker notebook:

`%%bash awscurl \ -X POST correct_database_cluster:8182/ml/dataprocessing \ -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \ -d '{ "inputDataS3Location" : "s3_bucket_1", "processedDataS3Location" : "s3_bucket_2", "processingInstanceType":"ml.t3.medium" }'`

And I am getting the following error message:

`{"detailedMessage":"Unable to load credentials due to invalid Neptune IAM. Please add a valid IAM role to the cluster or pass as a parameter to this request.","requestId":"a0525a99-1c5c-4b73-b080-2415f5b65913","code":"MissingParameterException"}`

I have checked that in the parameter group of the Neptune cluster I have a valid IAM role and the notebook has also the valid IAM role in the configuration. I am also passing the role that the Neptune cluster has in the request itself but still it doesn't work. I don't see any reference to this error in the Neptune documentation. I would really appreciate any suggestions to solve this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After modifying the cluster parameter group with the Neptune ML IAM role, you need to restart the database cluster to propagate the changes to the instance. You should also make sure that the role has trust relationships with both `rds.amazonaws.com` and `sagemaker.amazonaws.com` service principals.